# Is there a way to highlight my app in default app chooser dialog?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-launcher

my app asks user to choose it to be a default Launcher.
Everything works great, however during tests we noticed that users have problems choosing the correct app. It's mostly caused by a missclick.

Is there a way to highlight my application? Can I get somehow what is inside that app chooser dialog?

I can swear that I saw somethng like that...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to highlight my application?

No.

> Can I get somehow what is inside that app chooser dialog?

Only by building your own custom ROM and having users rebuild their device with that ROM. That dialog is provided by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<intent-filter>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for particular `Activity`.